# Filtering a form with multiple check boxes

Tags: ms-access, vba

What I have is a form which shows company information and also multiple contact subform that shows contact information, seperated by what the contacts job responsibility is(tabbed).

I have a combo box on the company form which displays the job responsibilities, and once a responsibility is selected it will show only company records with a contact of the selected responsibility. This is the code;

```
Sub SetFilter()

Dim ASQL As String

If IsNull(Me.cboshowcat) Then
' If the combo and all check boxes are Null, use the whole table as the RecordSource.
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT company.* FROM company"

Else

ASQL = "SELECT company.* FROM company INNER JOIN Contacts ON company.company_id = Contacts.company_id WHERE Contacts.responsibility= '" & cboshowcat & "'"
Form_Startup.RecordSource = ASQL

End If

End Sub
```

The company table will then only show records with a contact of the type specified in the cboshowcat combo box, without showing duplicate companies on the main form.

I then want to apply some further filters based on check boxes on the main form, which relate to fields on the contacts subform. These are activated by a button along with the recordsource code from above;

```
Private Sub Command201_Click()

If Nz(Me.cboshowcat) = "" And Me.Check194 = True Or Nz(Me.cboshowcat) = "" And Me.Check199 = True Or Nz(Me.cboshowcat) = "" And Me.Check205 = True Then
    MsgBox "Please Select a Job Responsibility"
    Cancel = True
Else

SetFilter
If Me.Check194 = True Then
Me.Filter = "cedit <=Date()-90"
Me.FilterOn = True
Else
Me.Filter = ""
Me.FilterOn = False
If Me.Check199 = True Then
Me.Filter = "((copt)='No')"
Me.FilterOn = True
Else
Me.Filter = ""
Me.FilterOn = False
If Me.Check205 = True Then
Me.Filter = "exsite is null"
Me.FilterOn = True
Else
Me.Filter = ""
Me.FilterOn = False
End If
End If
End If
End If

End Sub
```

At the moment the button filters out the selected contacts by category but if more than 1 of the checkboxes are checked it only uses one of the filters. How do I make it use multiple filters combined depending which tick box is ticked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter on multiple criteria then you need to construct the Filter string value to reflect that.  Eg:

```
Me.Filter = "cedit <=Date()-90 AND exsite is null"
```

Start with an empty string and go through the checkboxes, building the string as appropriate: if at the end of that process there's a filter string, apply it.

Here's a suggestion on how to do this efficiently:

```
Dim sFilter as String
sFilter=""

'...
If Me.Check194 Then BuildFilter sFilter, "cedit <=Date()-90" 
If Me.Check205 Then BuildFilter sFilter, "exsite is null"
If Me.Check199 Then BuildFilter sFilter, "((copt)='No')" 
'... more checkboxes...


Me.FilterOn = Len(sFilter)>0
Me.Filter = sFilter
'....


Sub BuildFilter(byRef sFilt as string, sAdd as string)
   If len(sFilt)>0 Then sFilt = sFilt & " AND "
   sFilt = sFilt & sAdd
End sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have had a play around and realised that I can only apply the filter once. For example; `code`If Me.Check194 = True And Me.Check199 = True And Me.Check205 = True Then
Me.Filter = "cedit <=Date()-90 and copt='No' and exsite is null"
Me.FilterOn = True
Else
If Me.Check194 = True And Me.Check199 = True And Me.Check205 = False Then
Me.Filter = "cedit <=Date()-90 and copt='No'"
Me.FilterOn = True
Else`code`               Thanks for the advice!